# Build string with another string in format function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what is the best way for me to build a string in format fucntion if I have second string, sub_str that is depended on other string main_str.
I have using string.format(string.format(), xxx). but it just not seems pythonic to me

```
def func(name, d):
    main_str = 'Hi customer {}'
    sub_str = '{}: Today is {}'.format(main_str.format(name), d)
    print(sub_str)

func('jo', 'wed')
func('Ma', '2017')
```

I want something like:

```
Hi customer jo: Today is wed
Hi customer Ma: Today is 2017
```

Comment: In this case, you could just do `'Hi customer {}: Today is {}'.format(name, d)` -- that doesn't hold in the general case I suppose and you're probably stuck with a solution like what you've written.  With that said, I'm no really sure that I can envision use-cases where you'd _need_ to do it the general way ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do all that in only one step :

```
def func(name, d):
    sub_str = 'Hi customer {}: Today is {}'.format(name, d)
    print(sub_str)
```

Comment: That's two steps. One step would be `print('Hi customer {}: Today is {}'.format(name, d))`. `;-)`

Comment: Yeah, but i'm talking about string building.

Comment: i cannot really do ```sub_str = 'Hi customer {}: Today is {}'.format(name, d)``` because in my case, main_str is actually a variable get from other class

Comment: i can use ```(main_str + sub_str).format(name, d)``` but it seems even more weired